# How to count the quantity of iten in every group on eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to group some records entries based on their statuses, however I just do not want the entries, but rather how many entries I have by status

This is my query :

```
CallItem::whereBetween('scheduled_date', [$startDate, $endDate])->get()->groupBy('status')->toArray()
```

That are the result:

```
array:4 [▼
  "swapping" => array:4 [▼
    0 => array:24 [▶]
    1 => array:24 [▶]
    2 => array:24 [▶]
    3 => array:24 [▶]
  ]
  "confirmed" => array:3 [▼
    0 => array:24 [▶]
    1 => array:24 [▶]
    2 => array:24 [▶]
  ]
  "canceled" => array:6 [▼
    0 => array:24 [▶]
    1 => array:24 [▶]
    2 => array:24 [▶]
    3 => array:24 [▶]
    4 => array:24 [▶]
    5 => array:24 [▶]
  ]
  "scheduled" => array:5 [▼
    0 => array:24 [▶]
    1 => array:24 [▶]
    2 => array:24 [▶]
    3 => array:24 [▶]
    4 => array:24 [▶]
  ]
]
```

But i want something like this:

```
array:4[▼
   0 => 4,
   1 => 3,
   2 => 6,
   3 => 5
]
```

only the size of the array in "swapping, confirmed, canceled, scheduled" and with no index.

How can i do this query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [map](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-map) function would be a good choice. Don't call to `toArray` yet:

```
$totals = $result->map(function ($item) { return $item->count(); });
```

All together:

```
$totals = CallItem::whereBetween('scheduled_date', [$startDate, $endDate])
                  ->get()
                  ->groupBy('status')
                  ->map(function ($group) { return $group->count(); });
```

Use [array_flatten](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-flatten) to then remove the indexes.

Comment: This was the result, the closest of all I needed

array:4 [▼
  "swapping" => 4
  "confirmed" => 3
  "canceled" => 6
  "scheduled" => 5
]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count using the database, you can use `DB::raw`.

```
$count = \DB::table('call_items')
            ->select(\DB::raw('count(status) as count'), 'status')
            ->groupBy('status')
            ->whereBetween('scheduled_date', [$startDate, $endDate])
            ->get();
```

This will return several objects with the `status` and a `count` per status.